# java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid URI

Tags: java, proxy, recaptcha

I want to use google recaptcha for my site. My network has a proxy. so i can't check recaptcha well in my network. then i get SSLHandshake exception. So i used below code to my java class. then i get `java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid URI` this exception.

Another thing i want to know is Using proxy can get a solution for SSLHansshake exception. I tried to get a free SSL certification for my localhost. but it was also unsuccessful. Is there another way to use recaptcha service without having a SSL certification.

i used my below code..help me to solve this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URL; 

import javax.json.Json; 
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.net.Proxy;

public class VerifyRecaptcha {
public static final String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
public static final String secret = "secret_key";
private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
//messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("risk.for.ip.block"));
 static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VerifyRecaptcha.class);

public static boolean verify(String gRecaptchaResponse) throws IOException {
    if (gRecaptchaResponse == null || "".equals(gRecaptchaResponse)) {
        return false;
    }
    try{

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);
        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        String postParams = "secret=" + secret + "&response="+ gRecaptchaResponse;
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        logger.debug("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        logger.debug("Post parameters : " + postParams);
        logger.debug("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //parse JSON response and return 'success' value
        JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.toString()));
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
        jsonReader.close();
        return jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.fatal("Error :>",e);
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```